# calculus, equation of a tangent, an easy question

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the tangent line :

$$\ln{xy}= 2x  $$
at point $( 1, e^2 )$

I end up with slope of $e^2$

so the equation will be $$ y= e^2(x-1) $$
$$ y = e^2x - e^2 $$

But the answer was just $$ y= e^2x $$ so appearantly they used $$ y=mx+b $$ instead of $$y=(x-x1)m +b $$

I know that my answer is wrong, but why?

Comment: Here in your last equation $b=e^2$ so it cancels.

Comment: @coffeemath to find be don't I have to substitute in the original equation? I forgot.

Comment: The given point was $(1,e^2)$ so you can either say $a=1,b=e^2$ and use $y-b=m(x-a)$ or you can use $x_1=1,y_1=e^2$ and use the same formula replacing $a,b$. Suggestion: google on "point-slope formula".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean: $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, so the equation becomes:

$$y-e^2=e^2(x-1)$$

$$y=e^2x-e^2+e^2$$

$$y=e^2x$$

Comment: In the first equation you mention you only need *one* point, along with the slope $m$. This is IMO best suited for tangent line problems and then one can multiply out if one wants the other form.

Comment: Now it looks like a good explanation (+1) [I don't know if your edit might have already been under way when my last comment got typed...]

Comment: I think so. But thanks! ;-)